# MS SQL - Multiple Running Totals, each based on a different GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Need to generate the 2 running total columns which are each based on a different group-by.  I would PREFER that the solution use the OUTER APPLY method like the one below, except modified to run multiple running totals/sums on different group bys/columns.  See image for example of desired result

```
SELECT t1.LicenseNumber, t1.IncidentDate, t1.TicketAmount, 
  RunningTotal = SUM(t2.TicketAmount)
FROM dbo.SpeedingTickets AS t1
OUTER APPLY
(
  SELECT TicketAmount 
    FROM dbo.SpeedingTickets 
    WHERE LicenseNumber = t1.LicenseNumber
    AND IncidentDate <= t1.IncidentDate
) AS t2
GROUP BY t1.LicenseNumber, t1.IncidentDate, t1.TicketAmount
ORDER BY t1.LicenseNumber, t1.IncidentDate;
```

Example + desires result:
[i.stack.imgur.com/PvJQe.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvJQe.png)

Answer (score 1):

Use `outer apply` twice:

Here is how you get one running total:

```
SELECT st.*, r1.RunningTotal
FROM dbo.SpeedingTickets st OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT SUM(st2.TicketAmount) as RunningTotal
      FROM dbo.SpeedingTickets st2
      WHERE st2.LicenseNumber = st.LicenseNumber AND
            st2.IncidentDate <= st.IncidentDate
     ) r1
ORDER BY st.LicenseNumber, st.IncidentDate;
```

For two, you just add another `OUTER APPLY`.  Your question doesn't specify what the second aggregation is, and the linked picture has no relevance to the description in the question.

Notes:

- The aggregation goes in the subquery, not in the outer query.
- Use table abbreviations for table aliases.  Such consistency makes it easier to follow the query.
- When using correlated subqueries, *always* use qualified column names for all columns.

Comment: Thanks lil guy. Pretty sick strat.